# Riddle: 3 people with the same name

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, riddle

In the Torah - 3 people with the same name - One is Jewish - One is a Ger - One is a Non-Jew?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reuel.

Jewish: the father of Elyasaf, nassi of the tribe of Gad (Num. 2:14 - elsewhere his name is given as Deuel, but Ramban there comments that they both have the same basic meaning and therefore are interchangeable). Also a Benjaminite (I Chron. 9:8).

Ger: it's one of Yisro's names (Rashi to Ex. 18:1).

Non-Jew: one of Eisav's sons (Gen. 36:4 passim).

Comment: This only works if you hold that Re'uel was indeed one of Yisro's names and not his father's name.