# Does anyone comment on the name Reu'el for Eisav's son?

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, vayishlach, esav

In Vayishlach (Ber. 36:10) Eisav has a son named Reu'el. While the meanings of/reasons for the names of those in Eisav's line are not provided, it seems to me that this name sticks out because it includes the theophoric -el construction which is often associated with Hashem (cf Yishma'el, Yisra'el, P'ni'el), and yet it was used in the family of Eisav, not known for its relationship with Hashem.

[In the case of the (grand)father-in-law of Moshe, it could be said that it presages his connection to Hashem as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuel and it fits in with the explanation for other of his names as per https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jethro-2]

Are there are commentators which explain why that name might have been used for that particular child of Eisav (does it predict or describe anything in his character which sets him apart)?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3199/759

Comment: I suppose the same could be asked about other Edomim with the E-l construct: Eliphaz and Magdiel (and also Meheitavel bat Matred, though I don't know if she was also of Edom). I heard that in archeological digs they discovered the name of an Edomite king carved somewhere, and he was called Kosel; Kos being the name of the chief Edomite deity. And just a few days ago I saw somewhere someone say that that Edomites had Hebrew names isn't a big question because they also spoke Hebrew - or at least a Hebraic dialect. "E-l" is a term of power, so Edomite "e-l" names would also have that meaning.